# I need to change image on tab bar controller in ios when iam moving out to another page through swipe

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I am just trying to show my tab bar selected when I come on the respected page by swiping it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)onSwipe
{
   [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
}
```